# Are imports useful when posting code on answers?

Tags: discussion, edits, code

Today I've seen this [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4509268/jad-chahine) editing multiple posts and he's being doing it for a [couple of days](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/34134433/revisions). His edits only remove imports on the code ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10503458)) and sometimes he improves something else, that, IMO are minor fixes that don't improve post or make it more clear or readable. And I've seen some edits before which do the same.(Sorry I don't have a link to this).

My question is: Is it ok to paste the `import`s (In Java) or `include`s (In C) libraries when posting a Question or Answer? For example see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34186885/2180785). I often paste the whole code (with imports) but, is it harmful or is it considered as not necessary? So I could change this in case I shouldn't be posting these imports or is it "ok" to have them in my Q&A.

Another example of this is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10503458) (Where the image was taken)
[image]

Comment: I personally like them to be there because there are cases where the code becomes ambiguous and it is not trivially clear what is meant. The best solution would be imho a smart folding option in the display like in IntelliJ that kind of disguises the included imports on the first sight until you decide you want to see them.

Comment: I personally don't like them as 90% of the time they're just noise, pushing the code I want to take a look at further down the page.

Comment: I only add it if I'm using a library other than what's standard (comes with the SDK), otherwise, I just omit them

Comment: I'll often include them when answering more beginner-type questions, if it's relevant and my answer includes a full program. That way, the OP can copy-paste my code and have a full, working example. (That said, I don't often post full programs anyway.) I do however make more use of `.*` than I would otherwise.

Comment: From past experience, I think imports are very useful, for example, in Java, I make use the `Timer` class in many of my examples, there are at least 3 `Timer` classes in the core API alone. I used to get a lot of comments about code not working when I didn't include the imports, so now, I include them to remove any possible doubt

Comment: @MadProgrammer or for example when OP names his / her classes as `Object` for example? Which conflicts with the `Object` class. In other words, you recommend to use them always, isn't it? As for questions and answers

Comment: @Frakcool It's my preference to provide imports to remove any possible confusion, and yes, I've spent way to much time arguing with posters over a class because the name conflicts with a API class.  Should we enforce it, probably not, but we should defiantly encourage it and having people remove them from questions/answers is counter productive - IMHO

Comment: Wow that user's edit comments are _terrible_. "Modifying <X>" Yes we know but **why** \*facepalm\*

Answer (score 80, accepted):

From your comment on another answer:

> Probably I didn't explained quite well, but, when I ask a question, should I add them or not?

## Absolutely

That is part of what an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is. To make sure a solution works before I post an answer, I'm going to copy/paste any code from the question into my IDE and make changes until it works.

Your example screenshot has 7 imports. Not only does that mean I now have to type out 7 imports<sup>1</sup>, but I have to go through all of the original code to see which imports need to be added.

Missing/incorrect imports are also the cause of error in some questions. Having that information helps us <del>close those questions as `a problem that can no longer be reproduced`</del> determine the problem with OPs code faster.

## Also in answers

Not everyone looking at an answer has enough knowledge to know where a class is imported from, or even that an import is necessary. I have seen examples of answers using popular third-party libraries, but not calling it out as such. For most people familiar with a language, it's obvious what the code is referring to, but for people new to the language, they aren't as well versed in the popular tools and libraries.

<sub>1. Some IDEs have support for automatic imports, but not all. Even a popular editor like Sublime Text only has one auto-import plugin for Python, and it is buggy and does not work in ST3.</sub>

Comment: *"That is part of what an MCVE is."*  Imports was one of the things I was thinking of when I made the first draft of the Minimal **Complete** Verifiable Example document..  So yeah, good call.  :)

Answer (score 32):

I would recommend that a code sample to be as close as possible to a running sample. This includes all imports, directives etc. Whoever takes the time to answer a question should be helped to concentrate on providing a solution or explanation, not trying to make the code compile.

Answer (score 28):

I would say it's up to the author of the post whether or not to add them to their code snippets.

If the author doesn't add them, it can be assumed that they're implied; Includes and Imports are a part of the code that helps an application or script run successfully; a missing dependency can be the **exact reason** why a piece of code doesn't work, so these lines should not be removed if the author includes them in their code snippet to begin with.

Comment: If it should be an MCVE, missing imports are a fail, though normally easily remedied.

Comment: So: never add imports to questions, always add imports to answers, never remove imports from anything.

Comment: That was my thought too when I read this answer @ThomasWeller but, in your opinion, should they be added too into questions?

Comment: @Frakcool: "never add imports to questions" - well, the OP might add them of course, but editors shouldn't

Comment: @ThomasWeller Probably I didn't explained quite well, but, when **I** ask a question, should I add them or not? Editing an other person's question with imports is not my idea.

Comment: @ThomasWeller Well, sort of. Add it to answers if it is relevant and missing. It's typically considered taboo by the community to edit (especially to remove) code that someone else has posted. You're right though that if it's missing from a *question's* code, and that's the problem, you should add it in an answer, not to the question (or sometimes VTC...).

Comment: @Frakcool If your MCVE doesn't work without the includes/missing includes are the cause of your problem (though hopefully you wouldn't know this otherwise you shouldn't be asking the Q in the first place :-)), then you should add them. If it does work without them, then you don't have to add them, but you can if you want to.

Comment: @Frakcool: yes, please add imports when asking questions yourself, because they may be part of the problem. I just recall a Java problem caused by a Thread which actually wasn't a `java.lang.Thread` but a `com.example.Thread` so it significantly changed the meaning of the whole code.

Comment: @TylerH *but you can if you want to.* so, there's no "no written rule" to write them or not, just a matter of taste?

Comment: @ThomasWeller While asking questions it's important then, and when writing answers, it's a matter of taste, isn't it? Shall we encourage this? Maybe requesting an edit to the MCVE page?

Comment: @Frakcool Like much of the "consensus" [tag:discussion] questions on Meta, there's no hard and fast rule. Even those can change if there's a good argument for it. Suggested behavior is determined by what those involved agree upon, but it's still only *suggested*. This is balanced out by the fact that the site is maintained by the community; pretty much anyone can edit a question or answer if they feel it's appropriate, or roll back your edit if they feel it isn't.