# Removing imports from Java code - too major?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I've noticed a number of suggested edits in the queue which do nothing but strip imports and package name from posted Java code. ([Here's an example.](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12056650)) All are from the same user.

At the moment, I'm rejecting these edits on the grounds that they're major alterations to the originally posted code. Is this correct handling, or should I be approving these edits?

Comment: I think it depends. If it is obvious which packages and imports to use you could live without them. If the question is asked due to faulty imports. they are relevant. But I'm not a java dev so maybe it is different in that world

Comment: Imports in android/java code are mostly useless and make the code harder to read (have to scroll past them) **unless** the issue is directly related to the imports. E.g. is `ActionBar` referring to support library or not?

Comment: Related / may be a dublicate: [Are imports useful when posting code on answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312045/are-imports-useful-when-posting-code-on-answers)

Comment: "I'm rejecting these edits on the grounds that they're major alterations to the originally posted code" Why are you doing this? What if the edits ["make it more likely that the asker will obtain the information he needs?"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288836/792066)

Comment: I think that while imports are not particularly useful in this context, that mass editing to remove them is not helpful.

Comment: @Braiam Personally, I consider imports to be a useful part of the code, and clearer/more easily readable code makes it easier to provide a useful answer. However, I recognize my opinion may be in the minority - hence this meta question. You offer an interesting counterpoint.

Comment: I think that it really depends on the question. Sometimes importing a wrong package (e.g. name collisions, wrong library, etc..) *is* the problem, so they shouldn't be removed. 

On other cases they are not needed and only add noise. For example, a problem caused by using `==` instead of `equals` along with unrelated long code that does many imports.

Comment: As long as imports are less than a page and are clearly separated from the rest of the code, anybody interested in actually answering the question should be able to defeat the mental hurdles posed by *scrolling down a bit*.

Comment: If the `import` is needed for disambiguation, it should remain. (E.g. `java.util.List` vs `java.awt.List`). In these cases, the imports make it easier for a user to reproduce the problem on their own machine.

Comment: Removing them might break a MCVE

Answer (score 49, accepted):

***DO NOT TOUCH THEM.***

Imports should be considered as part of the OP's code irrespective of whether they are actually being used or not. I have seen several questions raised by an OP only to find out that he was using the wrong class / package.

Keeping the OP's code as it is can help us in reproducing the issue quite quickly (by just copy-pasting code. And no, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> is NOT always a solution). In the same way, removing unnecessary comments from a post is also an invalid edit.

You can choose to remove the imports or the *unnecessary code* from your answer. As a rule of thumb, only edit things that don't affect the *technical details* in the post.

Side note: Do not add imports to posts that have no import statements. Drop a comment asking the OP to add them if it is necessary.

Comment: +1 "`Ctrl + shift + O` *is NOT always a solution*". Right, only a few users change from the default `ctrl + alt + O`.

Comment: +1, because half the time I had issues with things that should have worked perfectly, it was because I was importing the wrong class. Imports can be critical to getting the answer to a question right; without them, the code might actually work perfectly.

Comment: @null Some people use other languages and/or a different editor.  Imports aren't unique to Java.

Comment: Thank you @cimmanon. Note to self: label light-hearted puns on meta more clearly in the future.

Comment: i though imports not necessary. so i will never touch them.thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Imports in Android / Java code in questions and answers are often useless and make the code harder to read (have to scroll past them). Having said that, sometimes the issue at hand **can be** directly related to said imports. E.g. is `ActionBar` referring to support library, or not?

I would not say that including imports is a "problem". In the worst case it adds context. It should not warrant an edit, let alone mass edits.

As Maroun Maroun pointed out, it depends on the situation as well. Sometimes, OP doesn't know if the imports are causing a problem. In those cases, it would be wrong to edit them out without having investigated the context.

Tunaki [summed it up](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/30006654#30006654) nicely:

> Okay not to post them. But if they are there, there's no reason to remove.

Comment: Let me try this for you: Suppose I edit a post due to several issues I see, imports being one of them. Do I touch the imports or not? You can assume I know nothing about Java.

Comment: @rene I suggest you don't touch what you don't understand

Answer (score -11):

I find that imports can be done without - it really depends on whether you've imported the wrong package, but they are generally unnecessary, try to focus more on the code that you are editing rather than the problem that is being caused through error correction.

Comment: Note that the question is not "should I add imports", but rather "should I delete other people's imports?".

Comment: *try to focus more on the code that you are editing* you should not be editing code at all

Comment: @TimCastelijns I somewhat disagree; sometimes edits to code are useful. They should, however, be done only with great caution. Especially in questions and in highly upvoted answers.

Comment: @S.L.Barth you're not wrong. I spoke too soon

Comment: @AndrasDeak No, the question is 'should I reject edits where other people's imports have been deleted?'

Comment: @EJP you're completely right, thanks:)