# Is there a condition that makes a question always on/off topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

"Only a Sith deals in absolutes" isn't only applied to Siths, the human mind has a hard time dealing with stuff that isn't black and white, good or bad, true or false. That's why I like the current help page about "What topics can I ask about here?":

> Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, people
>   who write code because they love it. We feel the best Stack Overflow
>   questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question
>   generally covers…
>
> - a specific programming problem, or
> - a software algorithm, or
> - software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
> - a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

The only black and white part of the text is what SO is for: professional and enthusiast programmers, people that love to code.

But I've seen with increasing worry that people (myself included) seems to make broad statements about what is (not) on topic which are, well, absolute.

Is a question about a programming language: on topic. Is a question about dogs: off topic. <Insert your favorite/hated topic>: on/off topic.

I reckon that some allowances/restrictions are necessary for quality control and community control, but more lately than not, these allowances/restrictions has been evolving without minding either quality control or community control.

Get a hard look at the the new tags and the burnination requests, for example, a topic I've grown interest into. Tags are created/removed for topics are which are deemed on/off topic without a clear guidance what should (not) be allowed on the site. I don't feel the criteria these actors which take decisions are even following any guidance, but more like going with the flow, without any critical evaluation, but just doing what we usually do, without minding that maybe what we usually do may not be adequate for the context.

I expect disagreements, as always, but these disagreements are so bland and lacking essence that I can't figure out why are they even discussing the topic so passionately when it seems there's a profound lack of awareness of what the topic is even about. The only impression I've got is that these topics are merely rehashing a known and repeated script, mindlessly keeping the *status quo*. It is a depressing feeling.

I know I've been very vocal and passionate in certain issues, but I always try to be critical and rational in these issues and the ideas that get thrown around.

When evaluating some topics, I think we have to remember Marc's statement, when talking about HTML and CSS topics:

> IMO there is a level of implementation stuff that is development, not design.

I reckon that in some topics there stuff that it is development and stuff that is not development. There are topics that, even when everyone agrees that is development, there will be examples of people asking about non-development issues, and backwards.

There's no topic that is automatically on topic or off topic. There are on and off topic questions about that topic. We can take actions to deter off topic questions and promote on topic ones, but we cannot declare with certainty that all questions of a determined topic are on or off topic.

Comment: Can you summarize for me what your question is about? Is it something like _"Why do we do tag burninations, not every question tagged `apple` is off-topic"_?

Comment: I really don't get what you want to discuss here?

Comment: I've read it all, but I would still appreciate a TLDR section. There seems to be a lot of fluff and commentary which makes the question hard to parse.

Comment: Is the point that maybe we are closing more questions than we should? (Not my opinion, but my take-away from trying to understand the gist of your "question")

Comment: @CodeCaster Is more broader than that. Is about the scope of the site which has got... I have trouble to describe it... nonsensical? Haven't you noticed stuff that you have to stop and wonder "how this even make sense", as in why would this question be on topic and this other not? What is the reasoning that applies to everything, without consideration to context, like [Makoto example on this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/361823/792066).

Comment: @yivi there is stuff that tends to be on topic and stuff that tends to be off topic, but not because it tends to either side means that you can group everything related in a single bag.

Comment: ""Only a Sith deals in absolutes" isn't only applied to Siths, the human mind has a hard time dealing with stuff that isn't black and white, good or bad, true or false." Actually the human mind is quite possibly the **only** system that is able to deal with non absolutes, gray areas, and is pretty darn good at it.

Answer (score 7):

> There's no topic that is automatically on topic or off topic. There are on and off topic questions about that topic. We can take actions to deter off topic questions and promote on topic ones, but we cannot declare with certainty that all questions of a determined topic are on or off topic.

Suddenly, a question about *New Game!!*, an anime which aired in Summer 2017, [comes out of nowhere](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/41372/102).  But hey, it's on-topic here because it's *technically* an anime about programming, right?

Well, no.  That's not right at all.

There's a reason I didn't recommend that this question get migrated over here, even though a few others did:

- The question is about code that the OP has no ownership of, and as such, more accurate questions and things asked (like <s>an MCVE</s> complete code and exact errors) can't readily be provided
- The question is not likely to help other future *programmers* (but would satisfy the few curious anime fans)
- It's overly broad *anyway*.  We shoot-to-kill *lesser* questions than, "is my code an infinite loop?"

---

With that, I find myself largely disagreeing with your broader assertions, although this does also agree with your narrowing clause too.

I get where you're coming from on this; I've noticed that we've gotten a little...strange...when it comes to moderating content.  We're not exactly consistent with the standards or rules we apply, nor are we entirely clear on *when* those standards *shouldn't* be applied ([case in point](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/360522/1079354)).

To answer your base question - is there a condition that makes a question automatically on or off-topic - I have to say this:

## No, and we need to stop thinking so *algorithmically* about it.

While there are questions which are easy to identify as being "bad", **there's no clean pattern that can be applied to all questions or topics that make them all "bad"**.  Each question has its varying degree of "bad"; for example, A&E question I linked to above is bad for this site since we have adopted a standard of, "wanting to help the OP but the OP needs to do the leg work".  Since the creator of the code can't possibly hope to reply to our questions *about* the code, we can't reasonably support it.

But suppose *another* OP asked why their code was in an infinite loop, and the root cause was a genuine bug with their compiler, lexer, or interpreter.  We shouldn't automatically turn their question away just because it also happened to be about an infinite loop.

It gets to be a bit of a headache to think about topicality and how one should moderate on Stack Overflow, since there are highly opposed parties discussing [what we need to do with *duplicates*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/361371/1079354), let alone borderline content.  However, there's hope.

The main things I do to keep my head on straight:

- If I don't know, I don't take action.
- If I do know, I look for any angles that would make this question on-topic.
- If those angles don't turn the question into an entirely new one, it's easy enough to think of it as on-topic and I attempt to edit it in that direction.
- If I can't think of any way to make this question on-topic, I close it, ask the OP to make it more in-line with our questions, and go about my day.

Burnination is a little different; if I feel like the tag isn't about a specific technology or topic, then I start looking into the burnination heuristics (of which the process lists them) and see if the tag falls into that.  This makes tags like [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows) easy pickings, but other tags a lot less clear.  *That's* where I rely on the community; if we can at least reach a consensus on it, then that's good enough for me.

Comment: Exactly my point, there are obviously some topics that generate more off topic questions than other, but that doesn't automatically makes said topic off topic. (Of course, that doesn't mean that we cannot apply actions that deterrent the off topic questions)