# Need an MCVE be production-quality?

Tags: discussion, minimal-reproducible-example

Based on my interpretation of https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, example code should be short, only containing enough to clearly and accurately reproduce the problem at hand.

I recently posted [Why is init_color() ineffectual in Terminal.app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54137680/why-is-init-color-ineffectual-in-terminal-app) . Question comments have called out a practice (`assert`) that, while poor practice in full applications, is in this context a clear, short way to illustrate where the application is running as intended. @melpomene's concern is:

> It's sample code you've posted on StackOverflow. Someone somewhere will blindly copy/paste it into their codebase.

My concern is that replacing the `assert` calls with `if (...)` is more protracted and reduces clarity; and since this isn't Code Review, the asserts aren't pertinent to the question. So:

Should posts on SO endeavour to make perfect code, at the expense of legible and clear MCVEs, so that the innocent are protected and copypasters aren't bitten? Or should posts on SO try to maintain focus on the problem at hand, at the risk that the code is not appropriate for reuse?

Comment: I don't think so. An MCVE is about enabling other users to reproduce the problem.   Production quality code - which invariably has to deal with issues which may be outside the immediate problem space, such as network instability - is better dealt with on the software engineering site, IMHO.

Comment: Chicken-and-egg, code that exhibits a problem or bug is never production-quality.  Asserting in the question body that the real code has sufficient exception/error handling tends to be necessary to ward-off unnecessary comments.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The whole *point* of this exercise is for you to provide us code which *exhibits the same problem you're encountering*.  The intent is to *also* reduce any variables or any unknown unknowns into the equation, as you may wind up introducing some conflicting behavior with code which would not normally be run in production but *is* run when testing.  So it's fine to have stripped-down code, but don't introduce *new and divergent* functionality just for the sake of our request.

This

> It's sample code you've posted on StackOverflow. Someone somewhere will blindly copy/paste it into their codebase.

...is ***not*** your concern.  Your concern is to ensure that your code replicates your issue and is as close to the code you'd normally run as possible.

See also:  [Should an MCVE include boilerplate that's not required just because people incorrectly think it is?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/360522/1079354)

Comment: You often will need to introduce *some* new code for the sake of an MCVE.  For example, you may end up mocking out things that normally have complex behaviors with hard coded values, for the purposes of an MCVE.

Comment: Fair point.  I'll clarify to mean that I don't mean for the new code to be radically divergent.

Comment: If you blindly copy/paste code from a *question*, you're a unique flavour of fruitcake anyway.

Comment: @Gimby "Yes boss, I know it's not working, I got the code from someone on the internet who couldn't get it working either"

Answer (score 6):

While there are always exceptions, I would say that a good heuristic is that an MCVE shouldn't ever be doing something that would be *inappropriate* to do in production code, but it is entirely appropriate to *omit* things that would be considered necessary in production code.  A great example is error handling.  Production code is going to have lots of code devoted to handling error situations that can frequently be omitted from an MCVE because they don't come up in the issue being questioned.  You're *usually* not going to get called out for only handling the happy paths in an MCVE (and if you are you can usually just say it's omitted for brevity).

The other factor you should consider is what are the *consequences* of doing the thing that you're only doing for MCVE purposes.  Having some security vulnerability just because "this is test code so it doesn't matter" is dangerous.  I'm generally going to call that out if I see it, depending on context.  As an example here, if I see someone concatenating strings together to generate SQL to run I'm going to call that out and I wouldn't really consider "It's just for the MCVE" to be a good response, personally. Having code that's "arguably less readable, in my opinion" is...not the end of the world.  Honestly if someone's copy-pasting code without reading it then how readable the code is *doesn't matter* because they aren't understanding it either way.

Comment: I find it's more common for _questions_ to contain stuff like sql injection vectors.  _Answers_ to to be stricter about it, if only because the answerers want to demonstrate their credibility.

Comment: @snakecharmerb Whether or not it's more common, I'm interested in what the acceptable practice is. I'd agree that doing the wrong thing where the right thing is just as easy is something that should be called out no matter where it occurs - question or answer - especially for security vulnerabilities.

Comment: @snakecharmerb And in my experiences, questioners are usually called out for those insecure practices.  They're not just assumed to be "an intentional omission for the sake of brevity."

Comment: All - I think it would be best  if _questions_  avoided dubious practices, and think it is reasonable if answers highlight any insecure practices in the question.  I think it's reasonable for answerers to call out dubious in the question if it's reasonably within the original question parameters, and restrict themselves to polite observations otherwise.