# What feedback should I give if a post doesn't have import statements?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

### Background

When reviewing [first questions](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/), sometimes I find code snippets with no import statements. Sometimes, the import statements are implied within the tags, and it's only a singular library. I've seen this [post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312045/are-imports-useful-when-posting-code-on-answers). However, it doesn't answer how to give feedback to these questions.

### Possible solutions

I've thought about doing one of the following:

1. Doing a custom comment with a link to [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312045/are-imports-useful-when-posting-code-on-answers) and asking them to provide a MRE
2. Giving the automatic feedback:

> Question needs some code

How should I respond to these questions?

Comment: giving feedback that indicates specific changes that need to occur is usually more useful than "please fix your question"

Comment: @KevinB Yes, I thought as much. However, I'm wondering if the other way of responding would be constructive.

Comment: Some IDEs can automatically create imports *and hide them*, so the OP may not realise they need to include explicit import statements in their MRE. https://stackoverflow.com/q/25135328/4014959

Comment: I close vote with "Needs debugging info", and when there seems to be some hope of the author fixing it, write a comment about the necessity of a [mcve], sometimes pointing out the specific shortcomings.

Comment: @DanMašek "When there seems to be some hope of the author fixing it..."

I'd argue that you should do this whenever possible, rather than trying to guess whether the author will put effort into an edit.

Comment: Are these questions where the imports are *required* because otherwise it's ambiguous? Or is it just code which omits the imports for brevity and any common IDE would fill them in?

Comment: @VLAZ It depends. I see both all the time. It's mostly the small snippets for brevity though.

Comment: I would only request import statements when OP uses non-standard classes or you think OP accidentally uses incorrect classes without realising it. Otherwise they aren't needed, imo.

Comment: If you know what imports are necessary, and you understand the problem well enough to verify that the problem is reproducible with the normal imports, then just edit (or propose an edit) yourself.

Comment: The program `interface; function f(); end function; end interface; end program` requires no feedback about a missing import statement; the import statement in `interface; function f(); import i; end function; end interface; end program` is useless and confusing.

Comment: Tom and @VLAZ, I think a MRE *should* have explicit import statements, even for frequently-used standard libraries. Otherwise, potential answerers have to figure out if they were omitted for brevity or out of ignorance of their necessity. And it makes the code less confusing for future newbie readers. Also, not everybody uses an IDE. Sure, it would be painful to write Java without an IDE, but it's quite feasible to use a simple editor for Python.

Comment: @PM2Ring I'd really want to see more on why the Java code `Pattern.compile("[a-z]")` is *incomprehensible* and the *average user who looks at it* would be left wondering whether OP uses `java.util.regex.Pattern` or something else. Enough that they would not be able to work with this code to understand it or try to produce an answer. Do we have some record of Java questions having such complaints en masse? Because I kind of feel there isn't really such "confusion" going on enough to make imports a broad sweeping requirement.

Comment: @PM2Ring also, if you want to look for a better confusing example in Java, may I suggest `List` which exists as `java.util.List` - a data structure where ordered data is held and also `java.awt.List` which comes from the GUI standard library for Java and it is a list control where multiple values can be displayed and selected. Eclipse, at least last I used it, preferred to import the latter automatically because `java.awt` is first alphabetically compared to `java.util`. Surely, like Eclipse, this should be vastly confusing for all readers on SO, as well when not specified. Is that the case?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the answer to this is simple:
If the imports are not needed to answer the question then you don't have to do anything. (In case of a review task, you can just click **Looks OK**, assuming there are no other issues that need to be addressed).

If the used dependencies are ambiguous and you need to know where they come from to really answer the question, you can vote to close as **Needs debugging details**.

To quote the close reason (emphasis mine):

> The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the **shortest code necessary** to reproduce the problem.

With *shortest code* I imply the relevant imports or at least mentioning where these dependencies come from. After voting you may also leave a comment asking for the OP to edit these details in. Because without them, the potential answer is just guessing at best.

Comment: I partly disagree with this answer. Apart from ensuring unambiguous reproducibility, it is also the task of the OP to make it as easy as possible to reproduce the issue and start developing the answer. If the answerer needs to add boilerplate or imports then they are spending unnecessary effort that should have been spent by the asker. Some IDEs for some languages may be able to reduce the amount of effort, but it is better not to rely on that and just provide a MCVE that is actually complete.

Comment: @Marijn swathes of irrelevant, default imports (either implied by language, framework or library the question is tagged with) should not be made mandatory. It does not help with readability, it only adds noise. For most of my 3000+ answers I haven't had an IDE open; many questions can be answered with theory and pseudocode. If you need the imports to be spelled out for you in order to answer, perhaps you're not the best fit to answer.

Comment: @CodeCaster I prefer to test my answers to see if they actually work, even if I'm rather quite sure they do. For this I like to be given the imports in full so I don't need to re-type them myself. Furthermore it has happened various times that the OP comments "I tried your answer but it doesn't work for me", to which I reply "did you try _exactly_ the MCVE code as I have posted without any additions". Usually they haven't, instead they tried to incorporate it directly in their real code and made a mistake, but for this debugging approach to be successful all imports need to be in place.

Comment: @Marijn I'm not saying I don't test code I post. You don't have to re-type imports if you have an (online) IDE worth its salt. If askers are incapable of applying the principles from your post, then your answer either contains not enough guidance or contains unclear code, the asker just doesn't understand what you're trying to say or there's something else amiss. Nothing of that stems from missing imports in the question.

Answer (score 1):

There never has been and never will be a rule that code in a question must be copy-pasteable and runnable without any effort required from potential answerers, which is what seems to be implied here and in the [linked question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312045/are-imports-useful-when-posting-code-on-answers).

One would not always have to provide a list of imports that are implied by a language, framework and library; we have tags for those. In the context of my bread and butter, the .NET ecosystem, requiring askers to provide a list of imports for `System`, `System.IO`, `System.Threading.Tasks`, `System.Linq`, `System.Collections.Generic` and whatnot is going to add boilerplate that nobody reads and nobody uses because *any* IDE you use in .NET either adds those imports to new source files by default, *or* they [use implicit usings](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/implicit-usings-in-net-6) which tell the compiler to use those imports for every source file.

What is required, is that a question contains the **minimal** code necessary to reproduce **the problem**.

If **the problem** is a compiler/linker/interpreter/runtime error complaining about an unknown type, an ambiguous reference or a nonexistent member, then of course, the asker should provide their imports/usings/whatchamacallit. Ask for that in comments and at the same time close-vote as "Needs debugging details".

If the problem is about writing a particular query in Entity Framework (according to the question title, question body and/or tags), and the code compiles just fine but gives a runtime exception or unexpected data results, then **no**, one should definitely not be required to show in their code that they are `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`, that is implied by the context.

If the problem is about an algorithm, control flow, compiler rules, anything else and there are nontrivial, unobvious classes being used that are in the question's code but not actually related to the problem, then we do not need their imports; we need them to rewrite their code from scratch to create an actual [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

To circle back to my first paragraph and thereby my opinion: if you as an answerer cannot imply the imports being used from the question context and the problem in question has nothing to do with imports (or you are unable to deduct so), then sure, it might be that the question is lacking context (again: title, body, tags) or code (imports), but it could also be that perhaps you're not the best fit to answer that question in the first place.

It irks me to see questions being close-voted as unclear/non-repro where with a little experience in the relevant tags you can see that the OP has actually left nothing relevant out, but the close-voter lacks knowledge to answer it. That is not a reason to close-vote; just move along and find something you are able to answer.

Comment: Some imports are obvious, others not so much. Sometimes the problem even is with imports the asker has left out, maybe you think they've imported something but they've imported something else. Maybe they are having issues with circular imports. This answer seems to be generalizing too much and looking at things from only one point of view.

Comment: I guess your second revision does improve the answer. The initial revision to me seemed like an unrealistic expectation from answerers to be able to infer all imports an asker might come up with.

Comment: @Abdul my entire stance is this: 1. No, we should not require all imports to be specified on all questions. 2. If answerers recognize a question is missing imports that are relevant to the problem at hand (being a compiler/interpreter/runtime error about imports/types/members) then of course the question should include those, lest it being closed as non-MRE. 3. Answerers who cannot imply usings from title/body/tags where those are not relevant to the problem at hand (being _not_ about imports), should leave said question alone.

Comment: Seems like a slippery slope. First, skip the imports because they're "obvious" (in practice, often not). Next, skip the lang/lib versions because they're the latest ones at the time of posting. Don't mention Python 2 or 3, also obvious. No need for the React component header or props. Obvious. No need to declare a few variables, they're implied. Next thing you know the question is unanswerable or I have to spend 45 minutes trying to figure out how to run an answer. There's no _rule_ that the code be copy-pastable, but if you do adhere to this you all but guarantee a MCVE. Just add the imports!

Comment: @ggorlen slippery slope, reductio ad absurdum, et cetera. Anyone involved with Python will know Python 2 and 3 are worlds apart (and the former is now THREE years out of support). Those tags are adjusted for that. **Requiring** imports is impractical and unproductive, especially for non-scripting languages where you write your code within dozens of lines of boilerplate already, all with their own idiomatic, implied imports. You can't make a rule that imports are required else close-vote as non-MRE (which is what is being discussed here, and what you're proposing) for a minority of questions.

Comment: @ggorlen or to take the absurdism the other way: every C# question should begin with `public class Program { public static void Main(string[] args) { ... }`? Just so the answerer can copy & hit F5? I thought not. Some things are obvious, and if not (and not because you can't figure it out, but because through experience you know it's not!) - close-vote.

Comment: @CodeCaster I'm not requiring it as a rule, but there are way more breaches on the side of not enough information than too much information. It's clearly much better to assume it matters than not. It's very easy to toss in imports or tag a question Python 2 or 3 (that's just an example, maybe a poor one, so feel free to disregard it; it's less of an issue nowadays that Py 3 is the only supported option, but in the old days it'd often just be missing information that might require a comment to clarify--everything else applies).

Comment: Please show me a post where the inclusion of imports and use of `public static void main() {}` significantly detracts from a question or answer. There are dozens of examples I see every day to the contrary and it's exhausting to have to ask people for complete, reproducible code so I don't have to guess. I've had no problem writing 2k answers, almost always with a MCVE and versioning stated when there's a chance it matters. It's critical information I find consistently missing throughout SO, creating many headaches.

Comment: And yeah, if I have to spend more than 5 minutes figuring out any information that could trivially have been provided by OP which is necessary to run the code, it's going to get a close vote from me. If the import is `import java.util.ArrayList`, that's fine. I'm a reasonable person. I suspect many askers assume I can answer questions by looking at a snippet, but I almost always have to complete and run code and play with it to answer.

Comment: @ggorlen sounds like you know when it's necessary to show the imports to be able to write an answer, and that's exactly my point. The .NET tags I'm active in show for example one method even without the containing controller class, let alone show the usings (imports) of that file, or the setup for the dependency injection for the application, or the bootstrap for the program. Because it's just not necessary and not related to the problem. It's just not a problem, because everyone can work with the implied imports. It's not just one line, it's at least six for a simple console app in C#.

Comment: @CodeCaster Yes, but there'd be no harm if the extra import was included. I appreciate it when it's there, saves me a bit of time, especially with C#. A big part of the reason I avoid enterprisey languages like C# is that I often struggle adapting "obvious" code in SO answers to my use case, especially if I have no IDE handy (as is often the case with my job). I see no benefit in encouraging people to omit information. It never hurts to just provide all of the information and context and often hurts to leave anything out.

Comment: For example, I had a very hard time piecing together a solution to the simple task of deserializing JSON in C#, so I added my [own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73964945/6243352) that has complete packages, imports and context necessary to run and use the code fully. Almost every other answer in the thread had half (or less) of the needed information to get the thing running, and missing imports are a big part of that. Perhaps obvious to C# users, but not me. I wasted hours on that task.

Comment: @ggorlen it's not "an extra import", there's 5-10 per code block which are always the same given the context. Some stuff is better left implied, just like installing NuGet packages and using a compiler packaged with an IDE (Visual Studio (Code)). Not every C# answer would have to come with compilation instructions, not every C# question should come with a bootstrapper program, not every code block should have to explicitly mention all its imports when those imports can be implied. It adds noise. Questions are not supposed to contain runnable samples, answers do not have to be tutorials.

Comment: I don't think it's noise. Not everyone has your IDE, or an IDE. Build systems change over time. In my line of work, I often write code in over 20 different languages on a remote platform with bare-bones tooling. It's critical that I have enough information to run the code in the answer. If you look at that thread I linked, most of the answers are two-liners that say "try this" and zero imports, package versions or any context. I find it amazing that you can instantly run all of the code in any answer in that thread without any issues whatsoever. "Assume everyone knows" is not my approach.

Comment: @CodeCaster part of the philosphical difference here probably stems from the C# ecosystem and language. You're used to it, I'm not. Check out [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-can-i-deserialize-json-with-c/73964945#comment49730096_6620165) in the thread I linked.

Comment: @ggorlen you can't apply your situation to everyone's questions and answers. In the linked thread, you are answering 1. How to create a console app in C# that 2. Issues an HTTP request whose 3. Response gets deserialized into a dynamic object which you 4. Compile from the command line after 5. Manually installing a NuGet package and 6. Deploy including its dependencies. It is unrealistic to ask that level of detail from each post and yes that does add noise, regardless of the quality of the other answers.

Comment: @CodeCaster That's an extreme example, I don't expect that level of detail because part of my use case there is indeed special. But I think a few imports or versions is not much to ask from other answers in that thread, which is quite frankly a dumpster fire, coming as a non-C# programmer trying to simply parse JSON from an HTTP response. I'm just confirming that you have no problem immediately running any code in that thread as a C# expert.

Comment: And no, @ggorlen I don't just say that from my experience with C# and .NET, I say that as an avid reader, voter, answerer and educator. Yes, .NET has a lot of classes and a lot of legacy, and no, not everyone has a full-blown IDE, but again, and for the last time: my stance is that if using/imports can be implied from the context of a question or answer (title, body, tags), they do not need to be mentioned explicitly. That's all I'm saying.

Comment: You're entitled to that view, but I see wayyyy more problems from missing info than too much info. I've wasted so much time scratching my head due to lack of context and voted closed countless unanswerable, unrunnable questions. I've never seen a question or answer and thought "they provided too much context, imports and version information". Without a doubt, sometimes it's unnecessary, but better more than less.